# How To Properly do Rotations With Quaternions

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, rotation, quaternions

so I'm trying to make a camera that looks at an object I created and that object should rotate in response to mouse and keyboard inputs. Mouse gives the pitch and yaw rotations and Keyboard handles the roll.

What I managed so far was this class representing the quaternion camera:

```
QuaternionCamera::QuaternionCamera(vec3 direction)
{
    this->initial_state = quat(1, 0, 0, 0);
    this->distance = direction;
}

void QuaternionCamera::RotateCamera(float Xangle, float Yangle, float Zangle) {
    quat temp = initial_state.qFromAngleAxis(Xangle, vec4(1,0,0,1));
    quat temp2 = temp * initial_state.qFromAngleAxis(Yangle, vec4(0,1,0,1));
    quat temp3 =  temp2 * initial_state.qFromAngleAxis(Zangle, vec4(0, 0, 1, 1));
    initial_state = initial_state * temp3;
    initial_state = initial_state.qNormalize();
}

mat4 QuaternionCamera::ViewMatrix() {
    mat4 rotatingMatrixFromQuaternion = initial_state.qGLMatrix(initial_state, mat4());
    mat4 res = MatrixFactory::translationMatrix(distance);
    return res*rotatingMatrixFromQuaternion;
}
```

How this works is very simple, the when the mouse is clicked and moved, the RotateCamera function is called with RotateCamera(Pitch, Yaw, 0) and when the keyboard is pressed I call it with RotateCamera(0, 0, Roll). The problem here is that the object rotates around weird axis instead of rotating around its own axis.

To properly understand what I'm trying to acheive see this video:
[Video of Quaternion Functioning](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zjMuIxRvygQ)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calculating your quaternions wrong.

Your camera should hold a Quaternion Q, which I believe is your initial_state.
When you want to rotate your orientation, you just need to calculate a new quaternion as you do (quat temp) and apply it ON THE LEFT.

As quaternions are not commutative, you must apply it in the correct order, that being Q2 * Q1, where Q2 is your new quaternion and Q1 your old quaternion.